# What do the Pestilence and Inclement Weather armor effects actually do?

Tags: halo-reach

What do the Pestilence and Inclement Weather armor effects in *Halo: Reach* actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They only have an effect on the appearance of the character during gameplay. Pestilence makes a diseased looking cloud appear around the Spartan's head and Inclement Weather makes the Spartan appear to be engulfed in a lightning storm with the cloud near their head.